# Infinite power summation where no common ratio can be seen

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Problem in book states to evaluate the sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i^2}{4^i}$$

I can come up with the series S = $\frac{1^2}{4^1} + \frac{2^2}{4^2} + \frac{3^2}{4^3} + \frac{4^2}{4^4} + \frac{5^2}{4^5} + ...$

And 4S = $ 1 + \frac{2^2}{4^1} + \frac{3^2}{4^2} + \frac{4^2}{4^3} + \frac{5^2}{4^4} + \frac{6^2}{4^5} + ...$

If I subtract S from 4S I get 3S = $ 1 + \frac{3}{4^1} + \frac{5}{4^2} + \frac{7}{4^3} + \frac{9}{4^4} + \frac{11}{4^5} + ...$

I cannot find a common ratio to plug in to $\frac{1}{1-r}$ in order to figure this out.  I asked my professor for some assistance, and he said the answer should be $\frac{20}{27}$, but I cannot figure out what steps he took to get that.  He didn't explain it very well, and all other resources I've checked only show how to compute a geometric sum when there is a common ratio like $\frac{1}{2}$.

How do I determine a common ratio to figure out the sum?  I tried division by sequential terms, and that gave me a common ratio of $\frac{5}{16}$, but that left me with an answer of S = $\frac{16}{27}$, which isn't correct.

What am I doing wrong? Or what am I missing?

Comment: You used the trick of subtracting $S$ from $4S$, and got a simpler series. It's a good trick; why not try it again?

Comment: I must be a moron, because I don't see how I can subtract anything again.

Answer (score 3):

$S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^2}{4^i} \rightarrow 4S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^2}{4^{i-1}}=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(i+1)^2}{4^i}$

Thus we have $3S=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{2i+1}{4^i}=1+\frac{1}{3}+2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{4^i}$

$T=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{4^i} \rightarrow 4T=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{4^{i-1}}=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i+1}{4^i}$

Thus we have $3T=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^i}=\frac{4}{3}$, or $T=\frac{4}{9}$. Substituting this leads to $3S=\frac{20}{9}$, or $S=\frac{20}{27}$.

Comment: I can follow up through 3S = $1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2i +1}{4^i}$, but after that, I don't know how you come up with the next step.  How do you get to that next step?

Comment: First you can separate the sum with (2i+1)/(4^i) to 2i/4^i+1/4^i, which the latter one is a geometric series.

Comment: If you factor the 2 out, how does that not make it then be $2 \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i + \frac {1}{2}}{4^i}$?  This is the part that I cannot seem to understand.

Edit:  Nevermind, it's not factoring.  I see that now.  I'm still lost on where the $\frac{1}{3}$ comes from.

Comment: Before factoring out I calculated sum with 1/4^i. That is the reason that 1/3 is added in the second line.

Comment: I still have trouble with that.  One of the previous problems had the sum with 1/4 ^i, and that came out to 4/3.  How is this not 1 + 4/3?

Comment: The sum starts with i=1, not i=0.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty {i^2}{x^i}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty {[i(i-1)+i]}{x^i}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty {i(i-1)}{x^i}+\sum_{i=0}^\infty {i}{x^i}=x^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty {i(i-1)}{x^{i-2}}+x\sum_{i=0}^\infty {i}{x^{i-1}}$$ that is to say 
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty {i^2}{x^i}=x^2\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty {x^{i}} \right)''+x\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty {x^{i}} \right)'$$ and you know that
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty {x^{i}} =\frac{1}{1-x}\qquad \text{for}\qquad x <1$$ Now, things look to be simple.

When finished, replace $x$ by $\frac 14$ to get the final result.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^2 x^i = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3} \mid_{x=\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{\frac{1}{4} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{4} \right)}{\left(1- \frac{1}{4} \right)^3} = \color{red}{ \frac{20}{27}} .
\end{eqnarray*}

EDIT:

You are happy with a geometric sum ?
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i = \frac{1}{1-x} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now differentiate this equation with respect to $x$ ( use $ \frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i x^{i-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} 
\end{eqnarray*}
multiply by $x$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i x^{i} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} 
\end{eqnarray*}
differentiate again (The RHS is tricky & I will supply more detail if needs be)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^2 x^{i-1} = \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3} 
\end{eqnarray*}
finally multiply by $x$ and we have the result
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^2 x^{i} = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How do you get it to be $\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$  Where does the cube come from?  All of the formulas that I saw were $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

After that part, I can follow it to the answer.

Please explain it to me like you would explain it to a child, because I'm having the worst time understanding all of the logic associated with this.

Comment: OK, I haven't done differentials in like 7 years.  I don't remember anything about them.

Comment: Are you cool with $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: I'm cool with it, and I can understand the basic form, but above that, I lose it.

Comment: Can you do $ \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} $ ?

Comment: No, I can't remember how to differentiate.  I keep coming up with $\frac{x}{x-x^2}$

Comment: You need to use the chain rule ... does this ring a bell ? http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der04/der04.html

Comment: No, I tried following the examples on that page, but I can't seem to make sense of it.

Forget it, I can't seem to understand it no matter how hard I try.